# Pandas Reading csv file with " in the data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I want to parse CSV file but the data look like in the below. While using separator as ," it does not distribute file correctly to the columns. Is there any way to ignore " or escaping with regex?

3,"Gunnar Nielsen Aaby","M",24,NA,NA,"Denmark","DEN"
4,"Edgar Lindenau Aabye","M",34,NA,NA,"Denmark/Sweden"
5,"Christine Jacoba Aaftink","F",21,185,82,"Netherlands"
5,"Christine Jacoba Aaftink","F",21,185,82,"Netherlands"
6,"Per Knut Aaland","M",31,188,75,"United States","USA"

Thanks ins advance

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put the input data in text form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the csv file (assuming no new line between the rows):

```
with open('data') as f:
    raw = f.readline()
```

Some splitting and processing:

```
data = []
for r in raw.split('\" '):
    data.append((r+'"').split(','))
```

Creating the final dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think pandas can not deal with the CSV file when data has double-quoted and none quoted columns at the same time. Best way is using regular reading flat file functionality.